# Get only last week results from database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using this php [class](https://github.com/ThingEngineer/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class). it is helping me with database.

so one table called: `vocabulary` have row called: `datetime_uploaded`

example results from it: **2018-08-31-11-13-05**

now I want to get only last week results from database width this php class.

I have function to get last week days

```
function getLastWeekDates()      
       {
          $lastWeek = array();

          $prevMon = abs(strtotime("previous monday"));
          $currentDate = abs(strtotime("today"));
          $seconds = 86400; //86400 seconds in a day

          $dayDiff = ceil( ($currentDate-$prevMon)/$seconds );

          if( $dayDiff < 7 )
          {
              $dayDiff += 1; //if it's monday the difference will be 0, thus add 1 to it
              $prevMon = strtotime( "previous monday", strtotime("-$dayDiff day") );
          }

          $prevMon = date("Y-m-d",$prevMon);

          // create the dates from Monday to Sunday
          for($i=0; $i<7; $i++)
          {
              $d = date("Y-m-d-H-i-s", strtotime( $prevMon." + $i day") );
              $lastWeek[]=$d;
          }

          return $lastWeek;
      }
```

it gives me results:

```
(
    [0] => 2018-08-27-00-00-00
    [1] => 2018-08-28-00-00-00
    [2] => 2018-08-29-00-00-00
    [3] => 2018-08-30-00-00-00
    [4] => 2018-08-31-00-00-00
    [5] => 2018-09-01-00-00-00
    [6] => 2018-09-02-00-00-00
)
```

but have no idea how to get this from database.

my php version is 7.x

Comment: Have you read the documentation of your mysql class you use? There is query with BETWEEN where clause that will help you.

Comment: "SELECT vocabulary.* FROM vocabulary v WHERE v.datetime_uploaded > '$lastWeek[0]'"

Comment: as I'm first looking at php I can't make it done so I posted question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE DATE(date + INTERVAL (YEAR(NOW()) - YEAR(date)) YEAR)
      BETWEEN
      DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL WEEKDAY(NOW()) DAY)
      AND
      DATE(NOW() + INTERVAL 6 - WEEKDAY(NOW()) DAY);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will return last week's (last 7 days) records:

```
SELECT * FROM vocabulary
WHERE datetime_uploaded >= curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())+6 DAY
AND datetime_uploaded < curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())-1 DAY
```

If you already have both dates, you can use:

```
SELECT * FROM vocabulary
WHERE datetime_uploaded BETWEEN "2011-05-15" AND "2011-05-21"
```